# Find the velocity of water if power and mass is given

Tags: homework-and-exercises, work, power

A pump of 200W power is lifting 2kg water from an average depth of 10m per second. Find the velocity of water delivered by the pump?
$$P=200W$$
since the water is lifted per second
$$W=\frac{P}{1s}=200J$$
$$KE = W=200J$$
$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2=200J$$
$$v=\sqrt{200}m/s$$
But the answer is given as $2m/s$. Can anyone explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved using conservation of mechanical energy (i.e. [Bernoulli equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_principle)) which states (at steady state):
$$0=\left.\phi_{m}\left(\frac{p}{\rho}+\frac{1}{2}v^{2}+gz\right)\right|_1-\phi_{m}\left.\left(\frac{p}{\rho}+\frac{1}{2}v^{2}+gz\right)\right|_2+\phi_{w}$$

where $\phi_m$ is the mass flow, $\phi_w$ is the work done on the system, $p$, $v$, $z$ are the pressure, speed and depth respectively.

If you choose the positions $1$ and $2$ appropriately (e.g. where both pressures are equal and one of the speed is zero), this equation simplifies and allows you to solve for the speed at the outlet.

Note: by conservation of mass, the mass flow at position $1$ and $2$ must be equal.

Good luck

Comment: Please note that explicit solution to homework-type problems are not encouraged on this site.

Comment: @Danu - you are correct, i have removed the explicit solution and added a hint how to proceed instead.

Comment: @nluigi ok, thanks, and please be careful about this in the future too.